# Retrieving comments from MySQL tables with sqlmap

Tags: mysql, sqlmap

I added a table comment in MySQL (northwind database) as follows

```
ALTER TABLE northwind.fornitori COMMENT = 'tabella fornitori';
```

and I can retrieve the table comment with the following query

```
SELECT TABLE_COMMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'fornitori';
```

that shows the correct result.

Now, I want to retrieve the table comment with sqlmap, and then I executed

```
python sqlmap.py -d "mysql://root:pwd@localhost:3306/northwind" -D northwind -T fornitori --comments
```

but the output is

```
[11:23:54] [INFO] connection to mysql server localhost:3306 established
[11:23:54] [INFO] testing MySQL
[11:23:54] [INFO] confirming MySQL
[11:23:54] [INFO] the back-end DBMS is MySQL
back-end DBMS: MySQL >= 5.0.0
[11:23:54] [INFO] connection to mysql server localhost:3306 closed
```

Here, I cannot see any table comment. Is this a bug or is there something I am missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been solved in version 1.2.5.
Furthermore, `--comments` should be used with other options like `--schema`, as

```
python sqlmap.py -d "mysql://root:mypassword@localhost:3306/northwind" -D  northwind -T fornitori --schema --comments
```